# Loading Grid Definitions at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

The XAML code snippet is generated from data of a file.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height='0*'/>
   <RowDefinition Height='1*'/>
   <RowDefinition Height='0*'/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

My goal is to load this snippet into:

```
<Window ...>
   <Grid x:Name="TheGrid">
       <!-- HERE -->
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

So after compiling I can define the grid layout for my software before every launch.

I tried doing this:

```
using (Stream stream = GenerateStreamFromString(text))
{
   var element = XamlReader.Load(stream) as UIElement;
   grid.Children.Add(element);
}
```

The problem is that `XamlReader.Load(...)` throws an exception:

> The property element 'Grid.RowDefinitions' is not contained by an object element.
>
> Line number '1' and line position '2'.

The problem (in my opinion) is that in the loading environment there is no `Grid` element, so there is an invalid reference.

How can I solve this or how can I achieve the same goal easily?

Comment: Your XAML code snippet is invalid. It has no root element.

Comment: simply give the grid a name and then add row definitions in the .xaml.cs file.

Comment: You're trying to save a collection of `GridLength` values. This needn't and shouldn't involve serializing an entire Grid and dragging the XAML parser into the picture. Serialize `List<GridLength>` with normal XML, and when you deserialize, write a loop to add RowDefinitions to a Grid. Or use an ItemsControl; this has a certain something about it that may hint at an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML code snippet is invalid because it has no root element. Besides, a `RowDefinition` is not a `UIElement` that you add to the `Children` collection of a `Grid`.

Given the following input data:

```
string data = "<Grid.RowDefinitions><RowDefinition Height='0*' /><RowDefinition Height='1*' /><RowDefinition Height='0*' /></Grid.RowDefinitions>";
```

...you could use an `XDocument` and a `GridLengthConverter` to create the `RowDefinitions`:

```
GridLengthConverter converter = new GridLengthConverter();
foreach (var row in doc.Root.Elements("RowDefinition"))
{
    string height = row.Attribute("Height").Value;
    TheGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = (GridLength)converter.ConvertFrom(height) });
}
```

Comment: For some reason the converter converts the '0*'-s correctly but it converts the '1*'-s to '*'-s.

Comment: So? What's the difference? 1* = *. This is the same thing that the XAML processor does.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Then my main problem is that if I define the sizes as constants (100, 200, etc), it works, but if I use stars, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `XAMLReader` in this case - just add them directly using code, referencing your `Grid` by name:

```
TheGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0d, GridUnitType.Star)});
TheGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1d, GridUnitType.Star)});
TheGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0d, GridUnitType.Star)});
```

Comment: But isn't this violating some kind of mvvm principles?

Comment: The primary goal of MVVM frameworks is to provide bad, overcomplicated workarounds for all the problems they create when they accomplish their secondary goal, which is to help developers misunderstand MVVM as badly as the authors did.

Comment: @Ross Don't get MVVM mixed up with MVVM *frameworks*. Frameworks are orthogonal to the issue at hand, and I can promise you that the guy you're quoting is a huge MVVM fan (source: me). The above code certainly doesn't belong in a viewmodel, but it's not offensive to MVVM in code behind.

Comment: @Tudvari Not particularly, if you do it in code behind.